# Php array convert to jquery array issue for google map in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps

I'm working on php,i have making google map integration,i have database array value i want to pass javascript array how to do this, in static address array is taking for google map but i need pass php array to javascript variable please help.
I tried from long time to debug but not getting any leads. please help me in resolving this issue

Here my code:

```
    <?php
      include "db_connection.php";
      $locations=array();
          $query =  $conn->query('SELECT `address` FROM `tbl_master`');
           while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
             $locations[] = $row;
          }
            $locations = json_encode($locations);

    ?>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Geocoding service</title>
            <style>
              html, body, #map {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
              }
            </style>
          <body>
            <div id="map"></div>
          </body>
        </html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBAM5Cs2VsrOBs8Idqy0t0o6vw4hEU0Lys">
     </script> 
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var delay = 100;
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      function geocodeAddress(address, next) {
        geocoder.geocode({address:address}, function (results,status)
          { 
             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              var p = results[0].geometry.location;
              var lat=p.lat();
              var lng=p.lng();
              createMarker(address,lat,lng);
            }
            else {
               if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                nextAddress--;
                delay++;
              } else {
                            }   
            }
            next();
          }
        );
      }
     function createMarker(add,lat,lng) {
       var contentString = add;
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
         map: map,
               });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
         infowindow.open(map,marker);
       });

       bounds.extend(marker.position);

     }
//------here i need to pass database dynamic array value-------//
          //  var locations = <?php print_r($locations); ?>;

      var locations = [
               'New Delhi, India',
               'Mumbai, India',
               'Bangaluru, Karnataka, India',
               'Hyderabad, Ahemdabad, India'

      ];
      var nextAddress = 0;
      function theNext() {
        if (nextAddress < locations.length) {
          setTimeout('geocodeAddress("'+locations[nextAddress]+'",theNext)', delay);
          nextAddress++;
        } else {
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
      }
      theNext();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `$locations` is already a JSON string, simple echo will do.

```
      //------here i need to pass database dynamic array value-------//
      var locations = <?php echo $locations; ?>;
```

You can express the same with `<?= $locations ?>` syntax in a certain environment.

Comment: Hi Kita i tried your way , i alert location it is showing like : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: `alert` is not the same as outputting into html. Open source html and see there.

Comment: I think this working fine....

Comment: i'm checking the console log it is showing like : (1014) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},

Comment: @kumar the console is showing you an array of 1014 elements, without the actual contents. Clicking on them may show the actual content, in certain browsers like Chrome.

Comment: @Hi kita,  google markers also not showing sir.

Comment: it is showing like console log :​
0: Object { pg_address: " # 3/20, 1st Main, 1st Cross, Hosur Main Road, Adugodi, Bangalore" }
​​
1: Object { pg_address: " 24/3 Bazaar Street, Adugodi, Bangalore - 560030" }
​​
2: Object { pg_address: "# 430, Koramangala 7th Block, Beside Sai Baba Temple, Bangalore" }